# Алгоритм сложения интервалов времени

Tags: php, алгоритм, время

Привет! Подскажите алгоритм сложения интервалов времени. То есть есть допустим массив интервалов:
09:00 - 12:00
13:15 - 14:00
12:00 - 13:00

Нужно получить на выходе массив уже такой:
09:00 - 13:00
13:15 - 14:00

То есть если интервалы лежат рядом то объединяются в один (в примере соеденились и получились 09:00 - 13:00).
У меня получился только такой код:

```
$array[] = array('start'=>'12:00', 'end'=>'13:00');
$array[] = array('start'=>'09:00', 'end'=>'12:00');
$array[] = array('start'=>'13:15', 'end'=>'14:00');
$newints = array();
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    foreach($newints as $key=>$nint)
    {
        if($arr['start']==$nint['end'])
        {
            $newints[$key]['end'] = $arr['end'];
            echo 'test';
            continue 2;
        }

        if($arr['end']==$nint['start'])
        {
            $newints[$key]['start'] = $arr['start'];

            continue 2;
        }
    }

    $newint['start'] = $arr['start'];
    $newint['end'] =  $arr['end'];
    $newints[] = $newint;
}

var_dump($newints);
```

Вроде бы работает он правильно, но на мой взгляд код мог бы быть изящнее, и поэтому вероятно скрываются какие-то нюансы из-за которых могут быть баги. Пожалуйста, помогите)

Comment: а если интервалы пересекаются? например 09:00-11:00 и 10:00-11:30

Comment: Будут проблемы если интервалы могут подходить к концу суток - например 23:00 - 1:00 .

Comment: кстати есть решение за N log N а тут квадрат. И да, на счёт пересечений верное замечание.

Comment: А вот если сначала перевести все интервалы в количество минут от 00:00, то будет гораздо проще. Либо вообще в unix_time, если полная дата известна

Comment: Да, эти нюансы я не учёл. Но интервалы все в пределах одного дня идут в моей базе и пересечения невозможно, так как это время записи к человеку. Конечно было бы хорошо ,если бы кто-то предложил наиболее универсальный алгоритм

Comment: т.е. данные гарантированно корректны и не бывает `12 - 13 13-14 13-15` типо такого?

Comment: pavel, да, такого не бывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте замыканиями, чтобы повысить читаемость и сделать алгоритм универсальным:

```
$intervals[] = array('start'=>'12:00', 'end'=>'13:00');
$intervals[] = array('start'=>'09:00', 'end'=>'12:00');
$intervals[] = array('start'=>'13:15', 'end'=>'14:00');

$intervalsMerged = [];


foreach($intervals as $interval)
{
  if (!empty($intervals[$key]['already_merged'])) continue;

  if ($intersects = $anotherIntervalsInersectsWith($interval)){
   $intervalsMerged[] = $mergeIntervals($intersects);
   //тонкий момент - если интервалы уже слиты, ещё раз их учитывать не нужно
   foreach(array_keys($intersects) as $key){
     $intervals[$key]['already_merged'] = 1;
   }
  }else{
   $intervalsMerged[] = $interval;
  }

}
```

Замыкания предлагаю самостоятельно реализовать:

`$anotherIntervalsInersectsWith` - рекурсивно проверяет, с какими интервалами пересекается данный. Рекурсивно так как присоединение интервала к проверяемому требует проверки заново - т.к. границы изменились. Возвращает массив с корректными ключами исходного массива $intervals - подмножество от $intervals.

`$mergeIntervals` - сливает несколько в один: просто поиск минимума и максимума, но который немного осложняется переходом суток 24:00 -> 00:00 . Возвращает строку.

И не называйте переменную $array , желательно никогда :)

Comment: Спасибо, только как определять пересекаются ли промежутки? $anotherIntervalsInersectsWith, как она реализуется, хотя бы чисто условие

Comment: @iproger - цикл по $intervals , где проверяется что start2  < end1 && end2 > start1   || start1 < end2 && end1 > start2 (могу ошибаться - лучше нарисовать на бумаге интервалы - сразу ясно). Время преобразуется в числовое значение для сравнения - как писал rjhdby .

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду делать!

Answer (score 2):

Если изначальный массив строится обрезанием полной даты, то минуем этот шаг и формируем массив в котором ключами будут unix_timestamp от start, а значениями unix_timestamp от end. Потом сортируем по ключу и одним проходом массива делаем всю работу.

Если начальные данные именно время типа HH:mm, то примерно то-же самое, но ключи/значения формируем как HH*60+mm

Comment: Ого, спасибо, круто придумали!! Надеюсь я точно понял вас сейчас попробую написать код